# Yii2 use runAction() within beforeAction method

Tags: yii2

I have a MainController which extends Controller. All my app's controllers extend from MainController which includes various methods and properties which need to be accessible from any Controller.

Within my MainController is `beforeAction`, which does several things:

- Checks for redirects held in the database and performs them if the URL matches one in the DB.
- Generates `<head>` data for each controller
- Gets the language and country the user is looking at based on cookie and slug of the URL. (i.e. http://example.com/netherlands).
- Will render a generic page from a template if URL matches one from the database's `pages` table.

It's the last that I am struggling with. In my MainController I have this:

```
/**
* Before action, check all $this->before_actions satisfy. If no head_data provided, try and fill in some basics
*/
public function beforeAction( $action )
{

    // Run parent method first
    if (!parent::beforeAction($action))
        return false;

    // Check redirects
    $this->checkRedirects();

    if( $this->checkPages() )
    {

        // If not error page, loop through before methods
        if( $action->id !== 'error' )
        {

            // Loop through actions to peform and do them
            foreach ( $this->before_actions as $before_method )
                $this->$before_method();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Where $this->checkPages() contains the following:

```
/**
* Check for pages
*/
public function checkPages()
{

    // Attempt to find page for this request
    $page = Page::find()->where( [ 'permalink' => trim( str_replace( getBaseUrl() , "", getCurrentUrl() ), "/" ) ] )->one();

    // If found, load it instead
    if( !empty( $page ) )
        return Yii::$app->runAction( "pages/show", [ 'id' => $page->id ] );

    // Else, return
    return true;

}
```

The issue I am having is that if I go to http://example.com/story, because there is no StoryController, the returns a 404 error although the action does run and the view "views/story/show" is output.

How can I prevent this?

EDIT:

To add, the log shows that it first says:
`"Unable to resolve the request 'story/index'"`.

But then additional logs show:
`"Route to run: pages/show"` ... `"Running action: app\controllers\PagesController::actionShow()"`
..
`Rendering view file: /Users/stefandunn/Documents/Local Machine Development/views/pages/show.php`

So I am guessing it's the first log result causing the 404 status

Answer (score 0):

Add one last route that can catch any pattern and redirect to custom action.

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        //...
        '<any:.*>' => 'site/index' 
    ],
],
```

Comment: I was considering this as a proposed solution, however, I use the last rule to catch standard routes `<controlller>/<action>`. I ended up rewriting the htaccess file on Create/Update/Delete of pages.